# Export Dataset to Tileset with javascript in mapbox

Tags: export, datasource, mapbox

Is there any way to export dataset to tileset using javascript? I need to update frequently datasource but this is not reflected automatically on tileset.

Comment: Give references to what you have already implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same question and seems like it should be automatic, but it's not. One idea, if you have the ability to do this on a server and not the client, is to download the changed dataset, then upload the dataset using [mapbox-upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mapbox-upload), with the "id" as the id of the tileset you want to overwrite (which is just an eight character hash of the filename). This will not work of course if you want to do this on-the-fly in the browser. In that case you could just render the changed data using the raw GeoJSON from the dataset, filtering out the changed data from the tileset. Then on some recurring basis refresh the tileset from the dataset manually or with the upload api.

Answer (score -1):

I have found the answer of this question with the help of [this](http://sebastianpatten.com/mapbox-api-upload-example/) post. We can update Tileset (backend side) by providing geojson file and also tileset name. If the content of the file is valid, mapbox will automatically generate Tileset with all information that is provided within the file.

```
var MapboxClient = require('mapbox');
var userName = "<USER>";
var accessToken = "<SECRET-TOKEN>";
const fs = require('fs');

var client = new MapboxClient(accessToken);
// The first step is to connect to MapBox to provision some temporary access credentials to Amazon's S3
client.createUploadCredentials(function(err, credentials) {

         // Use aws-sdk to stage the file on Amazon S3
           var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

           var s3 = new AWS.S3({
                 accessKeyId: credentials.accessKeyId,
                 secretAccessKey: credentials.secretAccessKey,
                 sessionToken: credentials.sessionToken,
                 region: 'us-east-1'
               });

          function uploadComplete(err, upload) {
                if(err) {
                   console.log("An error occured creating upload: " + err);
                      }
                }

          function putComplete(err, resp) {
                if(err) {
                    return console.log("Error uploading file");
                 }

                console.log("Instructing MapBox to create TilSet...");

                // Create Vector TileSet
                client.createUpload({
                tileset: [userName, tilesetName].join('.'),
                url: credentials.url
                }, uploadComplete);
             }


             // Upload data to S3
          s3.putObject({
                 Bucket: credentials.bucket,
                 Key: credentials.key,
                 Body: fs.createReadStream(fileName)
                }, putComplete);
});
```

After the tileset is created/updated on mapbox i can add layers on the fly from client site by using the below code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
     if (layers[i].type === 'symbol') {
           firstSymbolId = layers[i].id;
           break;
          }
   } 

map.addLayer({
'id': TilesetId,
'type': 'circle',
'source': {
         'type': 'vector',
         'url': 'mapbox://<USER>.'+TilesetName
          },
'layout': {},
'source-layer':TilesetName
}, firstSymbolId);
```